# Firebase Firestore Security Rules recommendation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have created a cloud firestore database that requires constant creation and modification of more than one document/connection. In this circumstance, would these security rules suffice?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     
   
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: These rules are for firestore, not storage. Which one do you want to set rules for? And what do you mean by "would these security rules suffice?" What are your requirements?

Comment: Cloud Firestore

Comment: The rules help check if the user is authenticated and allow them to read, write and create new collections and documents

Answer (score 0):

The rule ensures any users are authenticated, but then allow them to do whatever they want. Is that what you want?

Comment: Honestly, yes. Because the design is such that a user must create and read collections/subcollections/documents, all that the same time.

Comment: I guess you mean "the design of my app', but you cannot assume a client will follow "the design". They can bypass whatever process you have in your app and make direct calls, only the rules protect you from abusive use.